# How to pick a random cell in list of cells but without duplicating the choice - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you populate a cell(s) (B24:B34) from a list of numbers (f2:f12) but without duplicating any of those numbers.

I just want to be able to drag the formula (from B24) down so i can add more numbers in the first column later on.

[image: Excel sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using few more columns. Let's say that:

1. You fill column C with `=RAND()` values,
2. Then you rank those random values within specific 'zones' (in case above, ranges are `B2:B12`, `B13:B23`, `B24:B34`) using following function (example for row 2): `=RANK(C2, C$2:C$12)`
3. Once you have a ranking, you can simply pick a value from the right side using `=OFFSET($F$2, C2-1, 0)` - it will pick value `C2-1` rows down and 0 columns right from `F2`. Since `C2-1` can be equal to 0 or more (up to size of one ranking), it will choose one unique value from list of values in F column. Note the limitation here: size of each ranking on the left has to be equal to size of elements to choose on the right.

Note that references above are in context of row 2. If something is a value in fixed position, it has `$` used to fix on specific row. For other rows, you should be able to fill down from row 2 (except 'zones' described in paragraph below).

To simply drag the contents of column with `RANK` function, you will have to feed `INDIRECT` function with calculated range of a 'zone' containing current row (I'd use `ROW` and `FLOOR` to calculate 'zone id' for a row, starting from 0, then calculate starting and ending point of a range by multiplying range id with its size, finally adding 1 to move everything below the header row). And I hope you know how to concatenate text that feeds the `INDIRECT`: to generate $F$12:$F$13, having value 12 in cell Z1 and value 13 in cell Z2, you need to wrap text using `''` and concatenate dynamic values from cells using `&` this way: `='$F$'&Z1&':$F$'&Z2`

Comment: I put =RAND() in C2 and i put =RANK(C2, C$2:C$12) in dD2. I can see how this is starting to work..but the 'To simply drag the contents' bit im completely lost - sorry.

Comment: I put =OFFSET($F$2, C2-1, 0) in B24?

Comment: No, you should put `=OFFSET($F$2, C24-1, 0)` there. But you don't have to fill row 24 manually, you can prepare data in row 2 and fill down for all zones. You should be able to fill down every column except the one with `RANK`, which needs manual input of ranking 'zone' reference (`C$2:C$12`) or combination of `INDIRECT` with `FLOOR` (which is an overdoing if you have just few 'zones').